# Saving to one table with a collection of ints in array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to save to a table in this format -

[image: Table]

I get the data as an array of ints for EmbellishmentPositionID in a viewmodel from checkbox values, i want to save them to the DB (SQL) as in the table. The EmbellishmentProductTypeID i get from the VM also.

This is all in MVC C#

Can someone help me out please? Ive tried -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ProductTypeVM viewModel)
{
  try
  {
    if (viewModel == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewModel));

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      var dataModel = _epdRepository.Table.Where(x => x.EmbellishmentProductTypeID == viewModel.Id);

      _epdRepository.Delete(dataModel);


      var model = new EmbellishmentProductDetailRecord();

      model.EmbellishmentProductTypeID = viewModel.Id;

      _epdRepository.Insert(model);
    }

    else
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewModel));

    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw;
  }

  return View();
}
```

Array picture -

[image: Array Pic]

Comment: Could you show the sample data array?

Comment: I'll add it to the question now

Comment: You can use foreach for this. Loop all data in viewModel.Values. Do you need a sample?

Comment: Yes please @Tomato32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
foreach(var item in viewModel.Values) //loop all array data
{
    var model = new EmbellishmentProductDetailRecord();
      model.EmbellishmentProductTypeID = viewModel.Id;
      model.EmbellishmentPositionID = item;
      model.EmbellishmentID = ??? //I dont know which value to bind
      _epdRepository.Insert(model);
}
```

Comment: @SimonR: Well played, my friend :))

Comment: That worked swimmingly, I should of known this stuff! Bad day for me i think.

Comment: @SimonR: You're a goddamn hero :d